# Query to return sales excludes results that are 0

Tags: mysql, sql, ssms

I've searched this and found this problem, and the solution that worked for most people (using an outer join) is not working for me. I originally had an inner join, and switched it to an outer join but I am getting the same results. This is based off certain account numbers and it shows their total sales. If an account has 0 sales it does not show up, and I need it to show up. Here is my query.

```
Select a.accountnumber, SUM(a.totalsales) as Amount, c.companyname
FROM Sales a LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts c on (a.Accountnumber =     c.Accountnumber)
WHERE a.Salesdate between '1/1/2016' and '1/27/2016'
AND a.Accountnumber in ('1','2','3','4')
GROUP BY a.Accountnumber, c.companyname
```

And I'll get results like:

```
Accountnumber | Amount  | Company
       1      | 250.00  |  A
       3      | 500.00  |  B
```

Since accountnumbers 2 and 4 dont have an amount, they are not showing up. I would like them to show up like

```
Accountnumber | Amount  | Company
       1      | 250.00  |  A
       2      |    0    |  B
       3      | 250.00  |  C
       4      |    0    |  D
```

How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: To clarify: You want to show ALL company names, regardless of if they have any sales associated with them and also return total sales for company accounts that have invoices? If so, try performing the select on the 'Accounts' table and then joining the 'Invoices' table.

Comment: I kind of worded that a little weird. But your first question is correct. I edited my query to make more sense. I want the query to return all acctnumbers/acctnames even if there aren't any sales for it.

Comment: What happens if you try a RIGHT join?

Comment: I've tried and the results are the same :(

Comment: what does sales table have for accounts 2 and 4? rows with 0 or no rows at all?

Comment: Actually, no rows at all.

Comment: ok, so see my answer below - the main issue is that you are using sales.accountnumber in your `in` clause, and also in your select. take it from the other table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that `RIGHT JOIN` will not work, since there are conditions in `WHERE`.
Try this:

```
SELECT
  c.accountnumber,
  COALESCE(SUM(a.totalsales),0) AS Amount,
  c.companyname
FROM Accounts c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales a
    ON a.Accountnumber = c.Accountnumber
       AND a.Salesdate BETWEEN '1/1/2016' AND '1/27/2016'
WHERE
     c.Accountnumber IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')

GROUP BY c.Accountnumber, c.companyname
```

Just to clarify, the problem is not which JOIN is used, it can be either, but using WHERE condition ON non-existing (NULL) values, since all not matched values from outer joined table are NULL anyway, any condition applied, practically make those joins inner joins (unless they are IS NULL conditions), see: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Good call. The conditions should be in the JOIN, not in the WHERE.

Comment: Test the latest edit, since there were some errors (wrong table alias)

Comment: This kind of worked. Except it brought back every single acctnumber in the table instead of just the 4 that I listed in the query. Why did this happen?

Comment: Move the check for the account numbers back into a regular WHERE clause.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize the second one was a WHERE. But I just changed it to WHERE and now its back to the original results. (Not showing accts with no sales)

Comment: Actually, scratch that. I must have had a typo somewhere but it just worked! Thank you so much, you're a genius.

Comment: Just to make sure though, say that account gets a sale tomorrow, it will change to the correct amount and not stay as 0?

Comment: Yes, it depends on your conditions in both ON and WHERE clauses, but yes it's future proof ;)

Comment: Thanks again @BlindandFurious you were a tremendous help.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two options.

1. Modify the query to select from the Accounts table first and then join the Sales table afterwards.

   ```
   FROM Accounts c 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales a on (a.Accountnumber = c.Accountnumber)
   ```
2. Use a RIGHT join instead of a LEFT one.

   ```
   FROM Sales a
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN Accounts c on (a.Accountnumber = c.Accountnumber)
   ```

Comment: BlindAndFurious pointed out there are conditions in your WHERE clause which apply to the entire dataset, so accounts without sales are not selected. Add your conditions to the JOIN, as shown in their answer.

Answer (score -1):

Change it to a RIGHT OUTER JOIN and it should work.

A left join says keep everything in the left table, IE the table before the left join, even if it doesn't exist in the second table. In your case I sure hope there aren't any sales that don't have accounts. To keep all the Accounts even if they don't have a sale you need a RIGHT outer join. Alternatively you could change the order of the tables and do FROM Accounts c LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales a ...

Edit..
Blind got it. RIGHT OUTER JOIN is what you need to use given the way you wrote it but then you have a null for all the values in the columns from the sales table  for 2 and 4 so the account number can't be in (1,2,3,4) or between the dates so they don't make it into the results.

Comment: I've tried this and unfortunately I am getting the same results. Except they are in a slightly different order.